# How can I get text to "snake" along a path

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, constraints, text-object

I want to get my text to both move and deform ("snake") along a path. I can get either of these to work but not both.

Here is an example of using the Follow Path constraint on the text:

[image: Follow Path constraint]

And if I disable Follow Path, I can get the text to deform using the Curve modifier:

[image: Curve modifier]

But when I try to combine them, the location of the text is displaced from its origin, so the deformation does not match the curvature of the path:

[image: Combined Follow path and Curve]

It seems there should be a way to get these two to work together properly, but I've not been able to find it.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Use the curve modifier only.

Comment: Thanks @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - that seems to work. So instead of using the constraint to animate, I just insert keyframes along one axis?

Comment: yes you only animate the progress on the Path. The Problem why it's offset if you use both is because it's additive, the Transform is applied twice

Comment: Use curve modifier and only animate linear movement for text object along the axis you have on the curve modifier.